# Setting Static Hostname on GCP VMs

Tags: hostname, google-cloud-platform

On AWS, setting a static IP is a breeze.

But it is damn right frustrating getting this to work on GCP.

I have used:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata $instanceName --metadata hostname=$instanceStaticHostname 
sudo crontab -e
@reboot hostname $(curl --silent "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/hostname" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
```

edited /etc/rc.local with:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname --static $instanceStaticHostname
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

but none of these has helped.

Please, anyone with a better sense of how to set static hostname on GCP that it stays?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1 - vi /etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/google_hostname.sh

2 - Clear file and write line hostnamectl set-hostname server1.example.biz --static

3 - Reboot